# Matlab R2015b 64 bits Error using mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I want to compile the following code using Matlab R2015b "

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "GLTree.cpp"
/* the gateway function */
//la chiamata deve essere DeleteGLtree(Tree)

void mexFunction( int nlhs,const mxArray *plhs[], 
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[1]) {


//dichiarazione variabili
GLTREE* Tree;
double *ptrtree;



 if(nrhs!=1){ mexErrMsgTxt("Only one input supported.");}




ptrtree = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);//puntatore all'albero precedentemente fornito


Tree=(GLTREE*)((long)(ptrtree[0]));//ritrasformo il puntatore passato

if(Tree==NULL)
{ mexErrMsgTxt("Invalid tree pointer");
}


//chiamo il distruttore

 delete Tree;  }
```

but I get this error "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MATLAB\GraphSeg\GLtree3DMex\DeleteGLTree.cpp:15:38: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
     Tree=(GLTREE*)((long)(ptrtree[0]));"

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @EluciusFTW how I can successfully compile the code  using Matlab R2015b 64 bits ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared mexFunction incorrectly. Your declaration:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs,const mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[1])
```

is not equivalent to:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

#### Answer to your question

You need to drop the `const` before `mxArray *plhs[]`.

#### Further comments:

You may want to check out this link on passing memory addresses back to MATLAB from a mex function. My instinct is that your casual use of a double and casting to a long (or even a long long) can be extremely problematic... It really should be a uin64, and for robustness, you may want some additional compile checks that the types all match up in that everything is 8 bytes...
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/75524-returning-and-passing-void-pointers-to-mex-functions

Comment: yes,  you are right,  thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess based on your code (I didn't compile it): On 64 bit machine, the address space has pointers of size 8 bytes (64 bit), and you cast a pointer to type `long` which is probably only 4 bytes long. If you want to cast you should use an 8 byte long type, such as `long long` (which is guaranteed to be at least 8 bytes)

Comment: thanks for your answer,  I compiled the code using"long long" cast  but I get this time the following error  "Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Error using mex
Cannot export mexFunction: symbol not defined
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: At least on Mac OS X with clang-700.1.81, long is 8 bytes. I'd imagine long is 8 bytes on modern windows compilers as well.

Comment: @malmo: That is a linking error. Maybe your mexopts file has wrong definitions. It's hard to tell based on this error.

Comment: @MatthewGunn On my system (visual studio 2013 on win 8.1 64 bit) long is 4 byte. This is really implementation dependent, and `long` has really only a guarantee on its minimal size.